# How to compare the database data?

Tags: android, firebase

How to write a code to compare my data in Firebase? In my Firebase under the medical is "Diabetes", when the user wants to buy the medicines, how to make the database auto compare the user information if the user has diabetes it will not allow the user to buy the medicines?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxe2q.png

```
    DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser mUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
    userID = mUser.getUid();

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void submit(){
    myRef.child("Users");
    myRef.child(userID);
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserInformation user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);

            if(user!=null) {
                if(user.getMedical().equals("Diabetes"))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Diabetes",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Not Diabetes",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                myRef.child("Medicines").child("Pain and Fever").child(userID).setValue("Acetaminophen");
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Userinformation

```
   public UserInformation(String name, String address, String phone_num,String gender,String country,String medicine,String medical) {
    this.address = address;
    this.name = name;
    this.phone_num = phone_num;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.country = country;
    this.medicine = medicine;
    this.medical = medical;
}

public String getMedical(){return medical;}

public void setMedical(String medical){this.medical = medical;}
```

Comment: can you show me your UserInformation  class

Comment: show me line 56 and 87

Comment: you need to make sure that every user in your firebase data structure has the same value in your UserInformation class

Comment: for example, some of your user does not have medical node then it will return null

Comment: But i try on the user which have Diabetes and it display the error

Comment: can you show more code

Comment: Which code? I have upload the code in my Userinformation page.

Answer (score 0):

```
  DatabaseReference mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();      
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  FirebaseUser mUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
  // this code will check if user has Diabetes or not
 mReference.child("Users").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       UserClass user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserClass.class);

       if(user!=null)
       {
           if(user.medical.equals("Diabetes"))
               Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Diabetes",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           else
               Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Not Not Diabetes",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }

   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

   }
```

});

Comment: How to use the Snackbar?

Comment: I not able to use the Snackbar i have edited my code can help me check?

Comment: add google design library to your gradle file 

add this, implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

Comment: or go to file->projectStructure->dependencies-> click green add button -> library dependencies ->  find the design library

Comment: i can't add this to my library maybe i not update my android studio because i scare later i update will get some error. So have other method to use without Snackbar?

Comment: it is not compulsory to use snack bar you can use Toast

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext,"blah blah",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: that findViewById(android.R.id.content use for?

Comment: Can you help me check my code? I have updated my code and when i click on Submit button it displays this error,.

Comment: Please help me, by end of October i need to done this project.

Answer (score -2):

In Databasehalper class

String sql ="SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE Name='"+datamodel_app.getFood_name()+"'";
        cursor= mDatabase.rawQuery(sql,null);
          if(cursor.getCount()>0)

{

//do your code here.

}

else{

}

Comment: dude he is using firebase not sqlite